# Node.js http request encoding question mark characters

Tags: node.js, encoding

I am trying to make a get request to a webpage which uses windows1251 encoding through the `http` client but the result contains question marks where the Cyrillic characters should be. I tried using iconv-lite but the characters are still not readable. Here is my code:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'example.com',
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 'Cookie': 'Mycookie=myvalue' },
  encoding: null
};

var results = '';
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    results = results + chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function () {
    let conv = iconv.decode(new Buffer(results), 'windows-1251')
    console.log(conv)
  });
});
```